# Events doesn't load in Full Calender

Tags: javascript, json, events

I'm trying to load events from DB but It loads only one event, I'm preparing JSON String ("EventData" in my below code) as per Full Calender JSON format and have converted into 
JSON Object. When I convert JSON String into JSON Object ("objEventData" in my below code). It shows only one event from  all the events.

Below is my code :

```
    var EventData = '';
    var date = new Date();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        var StartDate = formatdate(data[i].start.toString(), "mm-dd-yyyy").toString();
        var newDate = new Date(StartDate);

        var d = newDate.getDate();
        var m = newDate.getMonth();
        var y = newDate.getFullYear();

        EventData = EventData + '{' + "title:" + "'" + data[i].title + "'," + "start:" + "'" + new Date(y, m, d) + "'," + ' allDay: false,' + "url:" + "'" + data[i].url + "'" + '},';
    }
    EventData = EventData.substring(0, EventData.length - 1);

    var objEventData = eval('(' + EventData.toString() + ')');


    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events:
            [
                objEventData
        ]
    });
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are using it with php or asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

One way getting events on full calender is to read from a source. This might be a better option:

```
 $('#calender').fullCalendar({   

               eventSources: [
                       {
                           url: 'calenderdata.ashx', // or calenderdata.php 
                           type: 'GET',
                           data: {},
                           error: function () {
                               alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                           }
                       }
                ]
           });
```

Return the json data from the `calenderdata.ashx` (asp.net )or   `calenderdata.php` (php)